# Thunderbird hangs on pop3

Tags: thunderbird, pop3

On one of my machines, for the last 2 days, thunderbird hangs when connecting to a pop3 server. I previously had this problem because the TLS on the server was outdated and I had to change `security.tls.version.min`, but that's not it this time.

2 other PCs have no problem with that server, one even uses the very same accounts. All are ubuntu with identical configs. I started thunderbird in logging mode (`MOZ_LOG=POP3:5`) and cleaned up the output a bit for readability:

```
D/POP3  LoadUrl()
D/POP3  Initialize()
I/POP3  Connecting to server mail.mymailserver.com:995
D/POP3  Setting server busy in nsPop3Protocol::LoadUrl()
I/POP3  Entering NET_ProcessPop3 0
I/POP3  Entering state: 24
I/POP3  Entering state: 25
D/POP3  Clearing server busy in POP3_FREE
D/POP3  Clearing running protocol in POP3_FREE
D/POP3  LoadUrl()
D/POP3  Initialize()
D/POP3  ~nsPop3Protocol()
D/POP3 sink:  Calling ReleaseFolderLock from ~nsPop3Sink
D/POP3 sink:  ReleaseFolderLock haveSemaphore = FALSE
I/POP3  Connecting to server mail.mymailserver.com:995
D/POP3  Setting server busy in nsPop3Protocol::LoadUrl()
I/POP3  Entering NET_ProcessPop3 0
I/POP3  Entering state: 24
I/POP3  Entering state: 25
D/POP3  Clearing server busy in POP3_FREE
D/POP3  Clearing running protocol in POP3_FREE
D/POP3  ~nsPop3Protocol()
D/POP3 sink:  Calling ReleaseFolderLock from ~nsPop3Sink
D/POP3 sink:  ReleaseFolderLock haveSemaphore = FALSE
D/POP3  LoadUrl()
D/POP3  Initialize()
I/POP3  Connecting to server mail.mymailserver.com:995
D/POP3  Setting server busy in nsPop3Protocol::LoadUrl()
I/POP3  Entering NET_ProcessPop3 0
I/POP3  Entering state: 24
I/POP3  Entering state: 25
D/POP3  Clearing server busy in POP3_FREE
D/POP3  Clearing running protocol in POP3_FREE
D/POP3  LoadUrl()
D/POP3  Initialize()
D/POP3  ~nsPop3Protocol()
D/POP3 sink:  Calling ReleaseFolderLock from ~nsPop3Sink
D/POP3 sink:  ReleaseFolderLock haveSemaphore = FALSE
I/POP3  Connecting to server mail.mymailserver.com:995
D/POP3  Setting server busy in nsPop3Protocol::LoadUrl()
I/POP3  Entering NET_ProcessPop3 0
I/POP3  Entering state: 24
I/POP3  Entering state: 25
D/POP3  Clearing server busy in POP3_FREE
D/POP3  Clearing running protocol in POP3_FREE
D/POP3  ~nsPop3Protocol()
D/POP3 sink:  Calling ReleaseFolderLock from ~nsPop3Sink
D/POP3 sink:  ReleaseFolderLock haveSemaphore = FALSE
```

The hang happens after that last line and nothing more gets printed if I quit. Thunderbird otherwise works fine (I can sent via SMTP). There ARE messages waiting on the server. Any idea what else I should try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When, instead of clicking on [Get Messages] (for all accounts), I clicked on [Get message] (for just one account), it told me that (paraphrased) "the key is outdated, do you want to use it anyway?" and it started working again.

I mean, it would be the least, to tell the user that there is a problem with the SSL keys when doing a normal mail check, no ? I consider this a bug in Thunderbird.